Single trace is not propagated from mongo-Kafka- sink-connector to mongoDb
I am using Mongo kafka sink connector to send the messages from kafka topic to mongodb.
I have integrate the openetelemetry agent with kafka connector with following environment variable
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/otel_java_agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp
export OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=none
export OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=none
export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=grpc
export OTEL_PROPAGATORS=tracecontext,baggage
export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://...**

I am able to the traces till the kafka-connect but not able propagate to the mongodb database.
The expected behavior is traces should propagate from kafka-connect to mongodb database.
